# Cartesian product of arbitrary number of lists - Java

Tags: java, list, cartesian-product

I am trying to implement a cartesian product of an arbitrary number of lists. I have been thinking about this for hours, and I can't figure it out.

For example, if I have:

list letter = [1, 2, 3]
list num = [a, b, c]

then we will print cartesian product of:

- letter x letter
- letter x num
- num x num
- num x letter

However, if i had a fixed number of lists, it would be easy. But I don't know how to do an arbitrary number of lists.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a container of lists, simply for each list traverse the container and do the cartesian product.

```
for each i do 
    for each j do cartesian(a[i], a[j])
```

Comment: That would give you all combinations of "2D" cartesian products.  I suspect that for `N` lists, the OP wants the "`N`-D" product.

Comment: He was not clear enough then.